# How to cover code coverage for apexpages.StandardSetController

Tags: apex, visualforce, code-coverage

```
 public ApexPages.StandardSetController setActivityCon {
        get {
            System.debug('inside setActivityCon');
            //if the setActivityCon is created for the first time or if a new record is created then query from the child participant
            if(setActivityCon==null || setAct) {       

                String participantQuery = createQuery(interactionId);
                setActivityCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(participantQuery));
                System.debug('setActivityCon :: ' + setActivityCon);
                setActivityCon.setPageSize(size);  
                System.debug('pageNumber  :: ' + pageNumber );
                setControllerBirthday = DateTime.now();
                setActivityCon.setpageNumber(pageNumber);

            }            
            return setActivityCon;
        }
        set;
    }
```

Comment: Please share the test class

Comment: i don't have any specific problem but i need to cover these line

Comment: @user41664 why do you need test code to cover `setActivityCon` separately. Ideally it should be referred somewhere else in controller. So it should cover automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If You Need To Test ApexPages.StandardSetController Pass The Same Object 
Eg. Account Object

```
Account acc1 = new Account (Name = 'Account 1', Type = 'Type A');
insert acc1;
```

Then Call constructor with acc1 as parameter

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(acc1);
```

Ref Link:
[click](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093YaIAI) And
[Click](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BSHGIA4)